# How to connect to a Radius wireless network with wpa_supplicant using a username and password?

Tags: debian, networking, wpa-supplicant, radius

I am attempting to connect to a wireless network that uses RADIUS and WPA2 enterprise with the wpa_supplicant tool in linux.

Does anyone know the proper configuration for this type of connection?

My wpa_supplicant.conf file is as followed:

```
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
fast_reauth=1
network={
    ssid="MySSID"
    key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
    pairwise=CCMP
    group=CCMP
    eap=TLS
    phase2="auth=MSCHAPV2"
    identity="MyUsername"
    password="MyPass"
}
```

Additionally, here is a log file containing the results of the command `wpa_supplicant -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`:

```
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:fb:e4:25:4c:72 (SSID='MySSID' freq=5200 MHz)
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:fb:e4:25:4c:73 (SSID='MySSID' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:fb:e4:25:4f:12 (SSID='MySSID' freq=5200 MHz)
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:fb:e4:25:4f:13 (SSID='MySSID' freq=2437 MHz)
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:fb:e4:25:4f:12 (SSID='MySSID' freq=5200 MHz)
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:fb:e4:25:4f:13 (SSID='MySSID' freq=2437 MHz)
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:fb:e4:25:4c:73 (SSID='MySSID' freq=2412 MHz)
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:fb:e4:25:4c:72 (SSID='MySSID' freq=5200 MHz)
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:fb:e4:25:4f:12 (SSID='MySSID' freq=5200 MHz)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="MySSID" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-REENABLED id=0 ssid="MySSID"
wlan0: SME: Trying to authenticate with b4:fb:e4:25:4f:13 (SSID='MySSID' freq=2437 MHz)
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="MySSID" auth_failures=2 duration=23 reason=CONN_FAILED
nl80211: deinit ifname=p2p-dev-wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
p2p-dev-wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING 
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlan0 disabled_11b_rates=0
wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
```

Any information on what the correct configuration should be or debugging ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Edit: The results of the wpa_supplicant command with the `-dd` option added.

```
wpa_supplicant v2.4
random: Trying to read entropy from /dev/random
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
Initializing interface 'wlan0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf' driver 'nl80211' ctrl_interface 'N/A' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf'
ctrl_interface='/var/run/wpa_supplicant'
fast_reauth=1
Line: 3 - start of a new network block
ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=5):
     77 65 6c 6c 73                                    wells           
key_mgmt: 0x1
pairwise: 0x10
group: 0x10
eap methods - hexdump(len=16): 00 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
phase2 - hexdump_ascii(len=13):
     61 75 74 68 3d 4d 53 43 48 41 50 56 32            auth=MSCHAPV2   
identity - hexdump_ascii(len=5):
     77 65 6c 6c 73                                    wells           
password - hexdump_ascii(len=9): [REMOVED]
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='wells'
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-14-72:1
nl80211: Supports Probe Response offload in AP mode
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x80028 subcmd=0
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x80028 subcmd=1
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x80028 subcmd=2
nl80211: Supported vendor event: vendor_id=0x80028 subcmd=0
nl80211: Supported vendor event: vendor_id=0x80028 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 5 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with non-AP handle 0x55495490
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=040a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=040b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=040c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=040d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=090a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=090b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=090c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=090d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=0409506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=7f506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=0801
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=0a07
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=0a11
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=1101
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=1102
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x55495490 match=0505
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=5 linkmode=1 (userspace-control), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
nl80211: driver param='(null)'
Add interface wlan0 to a new radio phy0
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=00
nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm
nl80211: 2457-2482 @ 20 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 2474-2494 @ 20 MHz 20 mBm (no OFDM) (no IR)
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5490-5730 @ 160 MHz 20 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 57240-63720 @ 2160 MHz 0 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
wlan0: Own MAC address: 0c:1c:57:ad:69:70
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=5 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=0 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=5 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=1 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=5 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=2 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=5 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=3 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=5 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=4 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wpa_driver_nl80211_set_key: ifindex=5 (wlan0) alg=0 addr=(nil) key_idx=5 set_tx=0 seq_len=0 key_len=0
wlan0: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
nl80211: Flush PMKIDs
TDLS: TDLS operation not supported by driver
TDLS: Driver uses internal link setup
TDLS: Driver does not support TDLS channel switching
wlan0: WPS: UUID based on MAC address: f7a7f89c-383f-5fbb-8ea3-89e2442e1fe7
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
nl80211: Skip set_supp_port(unauthorized) while not associated
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
wlan0: Added interface wlan0
wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> DISCONNECTED
nl80211: Set wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=5 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
nl80211: Create interface iftype 10 (P2P_DEVICE)
nl80211: New P2P Device interface p2p-dev-wlan0 (0x4) created
Initializing interface 'p2p-dev-wlan0' conf '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf' driver 'nl80211' ctrl_interface '/var/run/wpa_supplicant' bridge 'N/A'
Configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf' -> '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf'
Reading configuration file '/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf'
ctrl_interface='/var/run/wpa_supplicant'
fast_reauth=1
Line: 3 - start of a new network block
ssid - hexdump_ascii(len=5):
     77 65 6c 6c 73                                    wells           
key_mgmt: 0x1
pairwise: 0x10
group: 0x10
eap methods - hexdump(len=16): 00 00 00 00 0d 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
phase2 - hexdump_ascii(len=13):
     61 75 74 68 3d 4d 53 43 48 41 50 56 32            auth=MSCHAPV2   
identity - hexdump_ascii(len=5):
     77 65 6c 6c 73                                    wells           
password - hexdump_ascii(len=9): [REMOVED]
Priority group 0
   id=0 ssid='wells'
rfkill: initial event: idx=0 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-14-72:1
nl80211: Supports Probe Response offload in AP mode
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x80028 subcmd=0
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x80028 subcmd=1
nl80211: Supported vendor command: vendor_id=0x80028 subcmd=2
nl80211: Supported vendor event: vendor_id=0x80028 subcmd=0
nl80211: Supported vendor event: vendor_id=0x80028 subcmd=1
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: interface p2p-dev-wlan0 in phy phy0
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 0 iftype 10 (P2P_DEVICE)
nl80211: Failed to set interface 0 to mode 10: -22 (Invalid argument)
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with non-AP handle 0x554a5ed0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=040a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=040b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=040c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=040d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=090a
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=090b
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=090c
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=090d
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=0409506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=7f506f9a09
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=0801
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=06
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=0a07
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=0a11
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=1101
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=1102
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x554a5ed0 match=0505
nl80211: Start P2P Device p2p-dev-wlan0 (0x4): Success
nl80211: driver param='(null)'
Add interface p2p-dev-wlan0 to existing radio phy0
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=00
nl80211: 2402-2472 @ 40 MHz 20 mBm
nl80211: 2457-2482 @ 20 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 2474-2494 @ 20 MHz 20 mBm (no OFDM) (no IR)
nl80211: 5170-5250 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5250-5330 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5490-5730 @ 160 MHz 20 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5735-5835 @ 80 MHz 20 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 57240-63720 @ 2160 MHz 0 mBm
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
p2p-dev-wlan0: Own MAC address: 0c:1c:57:ad:69:71
p2p-dev-wlan0: RSN: flushing PMKID list in the driver
nl80211: Flush PMKIDs
p2p-dev-wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> INACTIVE
p2p-dev-wlan0: WPS: UUID from the first interface: f7a7f89c-383f-5fbb-8ea3-89e2442e1fe7
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
ENGINE: Loading dynamic engine
EAPOL: SUPP_PAE entering state DISCONNECTED
EAPOL: Supplicant port status: Unauthorized
nl80211: Skip set_supp_port(unauthorized) while not associated
EAPOL: KEY_RX entering state NO_KEY_RECEIVE
EAPOL: SUPP_BE entering state INITIALIZE
EAP: EAP entering state DISABLED
Using existing control interface directory.
P2P: Add operating class 81
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=11): 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0a 0b
P2P: Add operating class 115
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=1): 28
P2P: Add operating class 124
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=3): 95 99 a1
P2P: Add operating class 126
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=1): 95
P2P: Add operating class 127
P2P: Channels - hexdump(len=1): 99
P2P: Own listen channel: 81:11
P2P: Random operating channel: 81:1
P2P: initialized
P2P: channels: 81:1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 115:40 124:149,153,161 126:149 127:153
P2P: cli_channels:
p2p-dev-wlan0: Added interface p2p-dev-wlan0
p2p-dev-wlan0: State: INACTIVE -> DISCONNECTED
nl80211: Set p2p-dev-wlan0 operstate 0->0 (DORMANT)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=0 linkmode=-1 (no change), operstate=5 (IF_OPER_DORMANT)
random: Got 20/20 bytes from /dev/random
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=5 ifname=wlan0 operstate=2 linkmode=0 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
RTM_NEWLINK: ifi_index=5 ifname=wlan0 operstate=2 linkmode=1 ifi_family=0 ifi_flags=0x1003 ([UP])
wlan0: Starting delayed sched scan
wlan0: Use normal scan instead of sched_scan for initial scans (normal_scans=0)
wlan0: Setting scan request: 0.000000 sec
wlan0: State: DISCONNECTED -> SCANNING
wlan0: Starting AP scan for wildcard SSID
WPS: Building WPS IE for Probe Request
WPS:  * Version (hardcoded 0x10)
WPS:  * Request Type
WPS:  * Config Methods (3148)
WPS:  * UUID-E
WPS:  * Primary Device Type
WPS:  * RF Bands (3)
WPS:  * Association State
WPS:  * Configuration Error (0)
WPS:  * Device Password ID (0)
WPS:  * Manufacturer
WPS:  * Model Name
WPS:  * Model Number
WPS:  * Device Name
WPS:  * Version2 (0x20)
P2P: * P2P IE header
P2P: * Capability dev=25 group=00
P2P: * Listen Channel: Regulatory Class 81 Channel 11
wlan0: Add radio work 'scan'@0x554a9da8
wlan0: First radio work item in the queue - schedule start immediately
wlan0: Starting radio work 'scan'@0x554a9da8 after 0.000043 second wait
wlan0: nl80211: scan request
nl80211: Scan SSID - hexdump_ascii(len=0): [NULL]
nl80211: Scan extra IEs - hexdump(len=126): dd 69 00 50 f2 04 10 4a 00 01 10 10 3a 00 01 00 10 08 00 02 31 48 10 47 00 10 f7 a7 f8 9c 38 3f 5f bb 8e a3 89 e2 44 2e 1f e7 10 54 00 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 10 3c 00 01 03 10 02 00 02 00 00 10 09 00 02 00 00 10 12 00 02 00 00 10 21 00 01 20 10 23 00 01 20 10 24 00 01 20 10 11 00 01 20 10 49 00 06 00 37 2a 00 01 20 dd 11 50 6f 9a 09 02 02 00 25 00 06 05 00 58 58 04 51 0b
Scan requested (ret=0) - scan timeout 10 seconds
nl80211: Event message available
nl80211: Ignored event (cmd=33) for foreign interface (ifindex 5 wdev 0x0)
nl80211: Drv Event 33 (NL80211_CMD_TRIGGER_SCAN) received for wlan0
wlan0: nl80211: Scan trigger
```

Edit 2: Results of `rkfill list` command:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: please run the command in debug mode with`-d` or `-dd` (even more debug level) and share the output here. `wpa_supplicant -dd   -Dnl80211 -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: Thank you for your response! I have added the results of this command as an edit to the original question.

Comment: could you please also provide `rfkill list` and `lspci -vv -s  $(lspci | grep -i wireless | awk '{print $1}')` ?

Comment: I have added the results of the `rfkill` command in Edit2, however the lspci command did not seem to run correctly for me.

Comment: And what is the result with `wpa_supplicant -Dwext -iwlan0 -c/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: I don't believe I have the wext driver, the result of the command is `wlan0: Association request to the driver failed` and `ioctl[SIOCSIWFREQ]: Device or resource busy`